# Remove the underline from questions tagged [underline]

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

Sorry for the mundane, unfun title, but I don't really feel like lumping a bug report *and* a burnination request into a single question. This is just the bug report, because there's more than just tags involved, and I don't want people to get sidetracked by a tag that admittedly does need to go away.

The following rule exists in the stylesheet:

```css
.t-underline { text-decoration: underline !important }
```

This and a number of other CSS rules appear with class selectors prefixed with "t-". It seems that this prefix is used not just for question tags, but for other purposes that aren't yet immediately apparent to me. As a result, the tag lists of questions tagged [underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underline) are, well, underlined:

[image]

```html
<div class="tags t-html t-css t-hover t-underline">
    <!-- ... --> <a href="/questions/tagged/underline" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;underline&#39;" rel="tag">underline</a>
</div>
```

Other rules exist, including:

```css
.t-align-center { text-align: center !important }
.t-help { margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 12px; color: #848d95; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.26666667 }
```

... except these aren't a problem because [align-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/align-center) doesn't exist and [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/help) is blacklisted.

Like I said, the [underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underline) tag probably needs to go away entirely, but that's not the root issue here (a burnination request can be created separately for those inclined). The root issue is that the "t-" prefix is used for a number of parts of the site layout, which can create conflicts such as this, which is ironic considering that the entire point of prefixing class names is to namespace them to prevent these conflicts in the first place.

This can be resolved by changing the prefix either in the markup or in the stylesheet.

Comment: `!important`  ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. We've added some special "atomic" classes for underlined text decoration and missed that `.t-` prefix is used for tags. Fix is now in repo and should be live in couple hours.

Comment: <u>Perfect.</u>